# how can I get facebook friends added within the last hours with FB.API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using

```
FB.API("/me?fields=id,first_name,friends.limit(1000).fields(first_name,id)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, friendsCallback);
```

to get the facebook friends list. 
But is there a way to manipulate that command to give me only the last added friends? Or even ordering the friends by added date would help already.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this in the API.
It is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.